# icCube: multiple dimensions in MDX output

Tags: mdx, iccube

The [documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/select_statement.php) of icCube states:

> However, a SELECT is not limited to two axes. We could have columns,
>   rows, pages, chapters, and sections. And you could still continue
>   beyond these by specifying a number for the axis.

Indeed, when I try using three dimensions on the demo Sales cube, it works:

```
select 
    {[paris], [london]} on 0,
    {[2005], [2006]} on 1,
    product.members on 2
from sales
```

However, when I try four dimensions:

```
select 
    {[paris], [london]} on 0,
    {[2005], [2006]} on 1,
    product.members on 2,
    measures.members on 3
from sales
```

I get an error message: `Unexpected number of axes (4) for the pivot table (expected:0..3)`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using a 4 axes query. However, it is left up to the client your are using to be able to display it.

For example, Excel accepts 2D results, the icCube pivot table is able to display results up to (and including) 3 axes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The quoted documentation of icCube claims otherwise.

Comment: The doc. is about the server that is able to SELECT on more than 3 axes. You can for example use a XMLA client (OLAP4J in Java for example) to retrieve a query with 4 axes. The error you get is because the client (i.e., the pivot table) cannot display the result.

Comment: I see your point, though the context suggests a different interpretation. But may be they mean that the `SELECT` inside the `FROM` clause can use any  number of dimensions.